# Is it possible to enable/disable use strict / warnings based on ARGV in perl?

Tags: perl

Is it possible to enable/disable use strict / warnings based on ARGV in perl?

I tried this code but it doesn't work. I believe it should generate a warning error at line where '$x = 2';

```
# Do this at the beginning of the script    
BEGIN {
        if ( $ARGV[0] =~ /^Y$/i ) {
            use strict;
            use warnings;
        }
        else {
            no strict;
            no warnings;
        }
    }

    $x = 2;

    print "x is $x\n";
```

The purpose is to enable warning messages only in development.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
use strict;
```

is equivalent to

```
BEGIN {
   require strict;
   import strict;
}
```

so the effect of `use strict;` are unconditional (since `import strict;` is evaluated before the `if` is evaluated).

Furthermore, the effects of both `use strict` and `use warnings` are lexically-scoped, so their effects are limited to the curlies in which they are located as always.

Use

```
BEGIN {
   if ( $ARGV[0] =~ =~ /^Y\z/i ) {
      require strict;
      import strict;
      require warnings;
      import warnings;
   }
}
```

or

```
use if scalar( $ARGV[0] =~ /^Y\z/i ), 'strict';
use if scalar( $ARGV[0] =~ /^Y\z/i ), 'warnings';
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it and works fine if ARGV[0] is Y but throws an error  if ARGV[0] is empty or not 'Y'.

Too few arguments to `use if' (some code returning an empty list in list context?) at /usr/opt/perl5/lib/5.8.8/if.pm line 7.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at test.pl line 3.

Comment: Should be fixed

Answer (score 0):

`use strict` and `use warnings` are lexical.  They only apply to the block that they're in.  If you had put the `$x = 2` in the same block as your `use` statements, it would throw an exception.